# Android Loss write permissions on Service

Tags: android, service, download, permissions, storage

I browsed a lot to try and find an answer, I'm trying to download a file through an Android Service,
I do check and grant permissions on MainActivity and also validate that it's been granted.
When I get in Service Class the app just get Permission denied.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks{

private static final int WRITE_REQUEST_CODE = 300;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView text = findViewById(R.id.text);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (text.getText().toString().equals("Started")) {
                text.setText("Stoped");
                stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DownloadService.class));
            } else {
                text.setText("Started");

                startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this,DownloadService.class));
            }
        }
    });

    EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, getString(R.string.write_file), WRITE_REQUEST_CODE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /*  MARKED CODE
DownloadFile downloadFile;
        downloadFile = new DownloadFile(getApplicationContext());
        downloadFile.execute("<https link>");*/
    }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    moveTaskToBack (true);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Move to Back", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
    Log.d("app", "Permission has been granted");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission has been granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, List<String> perms) {
    Log.d("app", "Permission has been denied");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission has been denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Service Class (only relevant section):

```
public class DownloadService extends Service {

 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

 if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Lost", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                                // download file and get it's locat path
                                String msg = downloadFile.downloadFile(imagePATH);
}
```

Main Activity do have permission the Service not!
DownloadFile is a simple class.

Some weird behavior, If I do execute MARKD CODE while i change DownloadFile  to be AsyncTask, I do manage to download and store the file. than when I switch back to the original code the Service also can Write files to storage.

What's going on?

Comment: AFAIK, you dont need permission to write to the directory your application uses, you only need permission to access the users files like photos. So if you are storing to app directory in your service, this is why it is working even without permissions

Comment: I try to save the file into /storage/.../Download/<file.name>  folder.

Comment: `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are not the same thing. You're requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the `Activity`, but checking for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in the `Service`. Prior to Oreo, requesting and having granted only `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` would automagically grant `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, too, due to a bug, but after that, you need to explicitly request `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. The write permission implies the read, so the easiest thing to do, if you need the write, is to just use `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` everywhere, so as not to get confused.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved the problem!